# Display list item that has the same subsite name

Tags: web-part

I have created a subsite and imported a list, from the original site, and inserted it as a web part.

Is it possible to modify this web part view so I can only show items that has the same name as the subsite?

For example: The subsite name is Test 23. In that list web part, there are items from Test 1 to Test 50. I want to show only item Test 23 (that is the subsite name).

How can I do that? Any idea?

Thanks!

PS: I have several subsites. It is virtually impossible to change manually every web part. My idea is to create a subsite model with that configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand , you have a list with a column contains subsite name , so you can use filter at view

- Go to your list
- Modify view from the above ribbon.

[image]

- At filter , Select you `column equal to Test 23`

[image]

**[Update]**

I agree with you to create a site template , and when you create a subsite you can run the following script at your list to create a filter using PowerShell Script.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://RootSite/subsite"
$list = $web.GetList("http://RootSite/subsite/Lists/YourList")
$query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='subsite' /><Value Type='Text'>Test 23</Value></Eq></Where>"    
$view = $list.DefaultView;
$view.Query = $query
$view.Update();
```

You can also do `foreach` for all lists if you are sure this field already exists at all Site List

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45119/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-display-list-item-that-has-the-same-subsite-nam).